# How can I use a regex to remove HTML tags from a String?

Tags: java, html, regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to use String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) to filter information out of an HTML document, i.e. HTML code. My aim is to remove all <>-brackets and the contents within them. To do this, I want to simply use an empty String ("") as the replacement String. For example, this:

```
<tr class='list odd'>
<td class="list" align="center">Do</td>
<td class="list" align="center">7.7.</td><td class="list" align="center">3 - 4</td>
<td class="list" align="center">---</td>
<td class="list" align="center"><s>Q1e14</s></td>
<td class="list" align="center">Arbeitsauftrag:</td>
<td class="list" align="center">entfällt</td></tr>
```

Should turn into this:

```
Do
7.7.
3 - 4
---
Q1e14
Arbeitsauftrag
entfällt
```

I'm completely new to regex and after watching some tutorials I came up with these regexes:

```
\u003C([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s|\S)+
[\u003C]([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s|\W)+\u003E
```

I built them using this website: https://regexr.com However, while they at least kind of seem to work there, they both result in a StackOverflowError in my code.

(Note that my IDE, IntelliJ, automatically makes each backslash into two backslashes. I think this is just adjusting the JavaScript regex to Java, but I could be wrong.)

TL;DR: How can I replace HTML tags with <>-brackets and their contents with an empty String using replaceAll (or something else if there is an alternative)?

Comment: Mandatory link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. More info [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105)

Comment: You can try `replaceAll("<^>*>", "")`, but you still will have to deal with [character entities](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references).  [Regular expressions are not suitable for parsing HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: `html.replaceAll("<.+?>", "");`

Comment: Is there any particular reason this has to be done using Java? With access to the DOM you could simply do something like this: `[...document.querySelectorAll('tr.list.odd td')].map(td => td.textContent).join('\n');` which will return the exact output that you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a proper HTML-parser like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), instead of string manipilation or regex. Jsoup provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating HTML data and is intuitive to work with. Using Jsoup your code could look like:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html =
                  "<html>\n"
                + "<head></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + "  <table>"
                + "     <tr class='list odd'>\n"
                + "        <td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">Do</td>\n"
                + "        <td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">7.7.</td><td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">3 - 4</td>\n"
                + "        <td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">---</td>\n"
                + "        <td class=\"list\" align=\"center\"><s>Q1e14</s></td>\n"
                + "        <td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">Arbeitsauftrag:</td>\n"
                + "        <td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">entfällt</td></tr>\n"
                + "   </table>"
                + "</body>\n"
                + "</html>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements tds = doc.select("td");
        tds.forEach(td -> System.out.println(td.text()));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Do
7.7.
3 - 4
---
Q1e14
Arbeitsauftrag:
entfällt
```

Maven repo:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```